# Pandas str.replace Exact Match Repeating Character

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Given the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a////b//','//','a/b/','/a/b/c/']})
df

        a
0  a////b//
1      //
2     a/b/
3    /a/b/c/
```

I need to replace all instances of '/' where there is more than 1, or one on either end.

The desired result is:

```
       a
0     a/b
1      
2     a/b
3     a/b/c
```

I have tried this with no luck (it just deletes all instances of '/'):

```
df['A'].str.replace('////','').str.replace('///','').str.replace('//','').str.rstrip('/').str.lstrip('/')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex to do this replacement, looking for one of

1. a `/` followed by another `/`;
2. a `/` at the start of the string; or
3. a `/` at the end of the string

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace(r'/(?=/)|^/|/$', '')
```

Output:

```
       a
0    a/b
1       
2    a/b
3  a/b/c
```

Answer (score 2):

Method by `split` and `stack` `groupby`

```
df.a.str.split('/',expand=True).stack().loc[lambda x : x!=''].groupby(level=0).agg('/'.join).reindex(df.index,fill_value='')
0      a/b
1         
2      a/b
3    a/b/c
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

First remove all `/`

```
df['a']=df['a'].map(lambda x: x.replace("/",""))
```

Then join using `/`

```
df['a']=df['a'].map(lambda x: '/'.join(x))

# output
      a
0    a/b
1       
2    a/b
3  a/b/c
```

Comment: This is dependent on all the values between `/` being a single character. It wouldn't work for `aa/bb`

Comment: @Nick that's correct but it seems that he has no consecutive characters. So I hope it will work for him. Thanks for letting me know that :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a////b//','//','a/b/','/a/b/c/']})
print(df)
df['a'] = [element.replace('////','/').replace('///','/')
        .replace('//','/').rstrip('/')
        .lstrip('/') 
        for element in df['a']]
print(df)
```